# Is it a bad idea store anything else than user information in FreeIPA?

Tags: freeipa

At $company, we currently have a setup based on an OpenLDAP with some homegrown^Whomemutated hierarchy, plus some other data stored into MySQL.

The OpenLDAP server contains data like internal users, clients contact (that can have access to part of our internal tools, so some have user/password information), freelancers we work with, and addressbook. The MySQL DB contains some duplicated data from those same users, and some complementary information, like data about clients' company, projects that depend on company and by extension to the client, etc.

My ideal plan would be to consolidate everything into one source of truth.

The interesting part of FreeIPA for us are:

- Provide LDAP entrypoint, all the internal services we use can bind to an LDAP server
- Provide REST entrypoint, would be ideal for our internal development.
- Ease of integration as it basically comes with everything needed to manage authorisation
- Somehow standard (by opposition of fully homegrown) hierarchy

As the documentation state, FreeIPA has a narrow focus, being an IdM, and not a generic LDAP store, but that means that if you want to extend your relation information (for example: for this project, we have those internal users, and those clients) you have to have some duplication in another tool (username/userid, groups in FreeIPA for authorisation, matching projects or company in the complementary datastore). That mean possible incoherent state between the data in both stores, need for some kind of synchronisation, etc.

So I am wondering if extending FreeIPA to store companies or project information for example would be such a bad idea, and if so why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bad idea, however you need to plan well. FreeIPA masters replicate data between then, so any LDAP schema extensions are better to maintain with packaging tools so that they exist on all systems. Same applies to the framework plugins.

Up until FreeIPA 4.4.1 there was an issue with externally provided schema extensions -- they were not included into install phase so you couldn't have your extensions installed from the very beginning due to objectclass/attributes missing at the point upgrade code performs generation of your plugin-specific ACIs, you only can add them later. See thread at https://www.redhat.com/archives/freeipa-devel/2016-August/msg00083.html for more details.

In FreeIPA 4.4.1 I fixed this problem (outcome of the discussion above) and now you can have fully separate extensions -- see example in my FleetCommander integration plugin at https://github.com/abbra/freeipa-desktop-profile/. I'm currently working on an extensibility guide for FreeIPA 4.4.1 or later, to replace my older guide (https://abbra.fedorapeople.org/guide.html) which became more or less outdated and doesn't cover maintenance/distribution issues as well as access controls design.

As long as you are maintaining your additions in a self-contained setup for FreeIPA 4.4.1 or later, you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for this response, I am going to take a deep look at all that :)

Comment: @Mayeu, I believe I answered your question, could you please mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: Yup, just wanted to read through the link you send before validating :)